# What is the single word for someone who gives nicknames to the others without any bad thoughts?

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I don't mean the namedropper thing. What am I, if I put a cool nickname to my friend without insulting them?

Comment: I don't know if there is a word for it, what makes you think there is?

Comment: The Cool Namer, The Nick Namer, maybe? I've given names to my pals, they're known by those names even after years.

Comment: "Namedropper" is **not** what you're looking for.

Comment: *The Caped Nicknamer*.

Answer (score 4):

**Nicknamer** — [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nicknamer)

> *nickname +‎ -er*
>   *‎(plural nicknamers)*
>   One who bestows a nickname

There is no particularly good or bad intention mentioned here, though.
I don't think there's any better answer to this.

An *un*related example:

> *"The Hudson River Cafe, which opened in May, is tucked beneath the West Side Highway at 133rd Street, in West Harlem, on that still-gritty stretch of 12th Avenue along the Riverside Drive viaduct that hopeful real-estate nicknamers have dubbed “ViVa,” for Viaduct Valley."*
>   <sub>[2007 August 19, Jonathan Miles, “Sanguine Sangria”, in New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/08/19/fashion/19shake.html)</sub>